# Channel Entries Tag Will Not Sort Using Category Parameter

Tags: channel-entries, categories

This is a strange issue, I can't get the channel entries tag to sort by category.  I only want entries that are in this category to display.

When you remove the category="13" it produces results but if it's there it will not.

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="people" category="13" limit="10" paginate="bottom"}
     <div class="person">
          {exp:ce_img:single src="http://XXXX.com/images/member_photos/{photo_filename}" max="125" }
          <h2><a href="{path=people/detail}/{member_id}/{url_title}">{title}</a></h2>
          <p>{person_excerpt}</p>
          <br class="clear_both" />
     </div>
    {paginate}
         <div id="pagination">                                                              
              {pagination_links}   
         </div>
    {/paginate}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Any tips will be appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure you have entries in that category? Are they future entries? Are they `open`?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `dynamic="no"` to your entries {exp:channel:entries} tag. This will stop EE from doing some things that it does automatically based on the page's URL.

https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/channel_entries.html#dynamic

Comment: I would suggest reducing to the simplest code and then adding pieces to see where things break. The category="" parameter is what you should use to show entries in a specific category.